# Моментальное обновления корзины в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть скрипт, который выводит товары из корзины при помощи Jquery, Ajax.
Но для того чтобы увидеть изменения корзины мне нужно постоянно обновлять страницу.
Как мне можно реализовать моментальное обновления корзины в реальном времени?

Вот сам код

```
    $.get('/cart-items', function (data) {
      var itemsHtml = '';
      var total = 0;

      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
          var subtotal = item.price * item.quantity;
          itemsHtml += '<tr><td scope="row" style="width:70%;"><div class="proudct_basket"><img src=' + item.productImages + ' width="85px"><a href="/' + item.slug + '">' + item.name + '</a></div></td><td style="width:20%;"><span class="price_basket" id="price_basket" data-price="' + item.price + '">' + item.price + ' грн</span></td><td style="width:60%;"><div class="amt"><span class="minus">-</span><input type="text" value="' + item.quantity + '" id="kol_' + item.id + '" class="quantity"><span class="plus">+</span></div> </td><td class="delete_product_basket"><a href="#"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18.41 5.59002C17.6233 4.80333 16.3478 4.80333 15.5611 5.59002L12.3561 8.79501C12.1594 8.99169 11.8406 8.99169 11.6439 8.79501L8.4389 5.59002C7.65221 4.80333 6.37672 4.80333 5.59002 5.59002C4.80333 6.37672 4.80333 7.6522 5.59002 8.4389L8.79501 11.6439C8.99169 11.8406 8.99169 12.1594 8.79501 12.3561L5.59002 15.5611C4.80333 16.3478 4.80333 17.6233 5.59002 18.41C6.37672 19.1967 7.6522 19.1967 8.4389 18.41L11.6439 15.205C11.8406 15.0083 12.1594 15.0083 12.3561 15.205L15.5611 18.41C16.3478 19.1967 17.6233 19.1967 18.41 18.41C19.1967 17.6233 19.1967 16.3478 18.41 15.5611L15.205 12.3561C15.0083 12.1594 15.0083 11.8406 15.205 11.6439L18.41 8.4389C19.1967 7.65221 19.1967 6.37672 18.41 5.59002Z" stroke="#979797" stroke-width="2"/></svg></a></td></tr>';
          total += subtotal;
      });

      // Добавление общей суммы товаров в корзине
      itemsHtml += '<div>Общая сумма: ' + total + ' руб.</div>';

      // Вывод товаров в шаблон
      $('#cart-items-container').html(itemsHtml);
   });
```

Comment: Тебе нужно "определить" некое событие и при его "наступлении" запрашивать данные и обновлять ДОМ... Есть у тебя на примете такое событие? Или все эти "обновления" делать с некой периодичностью по времени?

Comment: Мне просто нужно, если товар добавлен в корзину, то таблица с товарами обновлялась в реальном времени.

Comment: Значит нужно ловить событие "добавления товара в корзину" и в нужный момент запускать отработку запроса и изменения ДОМ...